# Angular 9 - Equivalent of $(document).ready()

Tags: angular, document-ready

What is the Angular equivalent of $(document).ready() ?

I want to execute a method once when the document is fully loaded (the method creates a component inside my component).

None of the [angular lifecyle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) is working (the console output that *this* is undefined in the early stages of the lifecycle, meaning that the component/class is not instanciated. On the late stages, the component is created a large number of times, ultimately freezing the navigator.)

Comment: can you elaborate what is that you're trying!

Comment: post some code with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, so to answer the question : **the angular hook ngAfterViewInit is an equivalent of $(document).ready()**.

**I do not say it is the only way**, as it may depend of what you are trying to do (I am new to Angular, so I can not be sure).

Here is the code. It is more about a way to create a child component after the document is ready than it is about calling a method once the document is ready, so most of it is beyond the scope of the question.

---

#### HTML

```html
<div>
    <!-- Template that can contain multiple components of any kind. 
         I want it to contain a 'ComponentA' before the page is rendered. -->
    <template #containerForChildrenComponents></template>
</div>
```

#### TypeSript

```js
export class MainComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('containerForChildrenComponents', {read: ViewContainerRef}) entry: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private readonly resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Call the method creating a child component of class 'ComponentA' inside the template
        this.createChildComponentA();
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }

    createChildComponentA() {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentA);
        const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
        // ...
    }
}
```